# Stream down file with strapi

Tags: javascript, strapi

after few days of testing and trying I am stuck...

My goal is, to stream an audio file down to client. With range headers and so on.
Important, I need a stream, coz' I am planing to implement some analytics.

What I have done:

I have a custom api

```js
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  streamFile: async (ctx, next, i) => {
    const mediaId = ctx.params.id;
    const entry = await strapi.entityService.findOne('plugin::upload.file', mediaId, {});
    const file = path.join(__dirname, '/../../../../public/' + entry.url);

    let stats = fs.statSync(file);
    let start, end;
    let total = stats.size;
    let range = ctx.req.headers.range;

    if (range) {
      let positions = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
      start = parseInt(positions[0], 10);
      end = positions[1] ? parseInt(positions[1], 10) : total - 1;
    } else {
      start = 0;
      end = total - 1;
    }

    let chunksize = (end - start) + 1;
    let stream = fs.createReadStream(file, { start: start, end: end })

    ctx.res.writeHead(206, {
      "Content-Range": "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + total,
      "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
      "Content-Length": chunksize,
      "Content-Type": entry.mime
    });

    ctx.status = 206;

    await next();

    ctx.body = stream;
  }
};
```

If I call the url directly (no audio client) I receive an error in browser like unsupported type.

When I use  tag, I see this in network

[image]
[image]

Any idea what to try?

PS: file is loaded correclty, the stats are there and overall only stream is not working